# Get Calendly meeting UUID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, backend, calendly

Is there anyway to get the UUID of a scheduled meeting in calendly? I'm not able to generate it via API JSON response because the user will be booking the appointment via a `scheduled_url` (which is a redirect link from a GET response).

```rb
require 'httparty'

class CalendlyController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :check_auth

  def user_event_types
    user_uri = ENV['CALENDLY_USER_URI'] # Replace with specific user URI
    calendly_api_url = "https://api.calendly.com/event_types?user=#{user_uri}"

    headers = {
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
      'Authorization' => "Bearer #{ENV['CALENDLY_TOKEN']}"
    }

    response = HTTParty.get(calendly_api_url, headers: headers)
    data = JSON.parse(response.body)

    render json: data
  end
end
```

My sample response to this kind of API request is something like this:

```json
{
  "resource": {
    "uri": "https://api.calendly.com/event_types/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
    "name": "15 Minute Meeting",
    "active": true,
    "booking_method": "instant",
    "slug": "acmesales",
    "scheduling_url": "https://calendly.com/acmesales",
    "duration": 30,
    "kind": "solo",
    "pooling_type": "round_robin",
    "type": "StandardEventType",
    "color": "#fff200",
    "created_at": "2019-01-02T03:04:05.678123Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-08-07T06:05:04.321123Z",
    "internal_note": "Internal note",
    "description_plain": "15 Minute Meeting",
    "description_html": "<p>15 Minute Meeting</p>",
    "profile": {
      "type": "User",
      "name": "Tamara Jones",
      "owner": "https://api.calendly.com/users/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
    },
}
```

As you can see above, I don't really have a controller for creating a scheduled event since the calendly site does it for me automatically when I redirect them to the `scheduling_url` from the JSON response.

I'm trying to make a GET request to `https://api.calendly.com/scheduled_events/{uuid}` so I can extract the details of the event since I'll be using some of those values/attributes for my database.

**Another concern** as well, I have an **Appointment** table/entity in my database, ideally it should be created (via POST) every after successful booking. However, like I mentioned earlier, the appointment is being created via the calendly link and not via a post request/controller. So I was thinking of pulling those event details I mentioned above instead and use those to instantiate/create an appointment table/entity every time an appointment is booked through the calendly scheduling_url. Unless there is a better/more efficient way to do it?

For more info, below is are my models and associations (I'm using Rails and React btw):

```
class Dietitian < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :dietitian
  belongs_to :patient
  has_one :record
end

class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :records
  has_many :dietitians, through: :appointments
end

class Record < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :appointment
  belongs_to :patient
end
```

Comment: To start with you should absolutely move this functionality out of the controller and into a separate class. I would put it in `app/clients` and use HTTParty as a mixin in the client class instead of proceedurally. Controllers are very hard to test and should not be contacting an application boundry directly. You also do not need  `require 'httparty'` as gems are required by Bundler when the app boots.

Comment: By using HTTParty as a mixin I mean something like `class CalendlyClient; include HTTParty; format :json; base_url 'https://api.calendly.com/', ...`.